# Questions based on tenants in SP 2013 Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, multi-tenancy

I have set of question based on tenants answer of which is not
   correctly known till now. Please reply inline.

- What is the proper meaning of tenant in SP 2013 Office 365?
- Do we need a tenant to implement SharePoint hosted app? Auto hosted app? Provider hosted    app?
- Do we need tenant in development environment?
- MS create tenant for you in office 365? I guess yes.
- At what scope MS create client?

Please explain inline and in details.

Thanking you.

Answer (score 3):

What is a tenant? From [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179896(v=office.15).aspx#Tenant) MSDN article:

> A SharePoint 2013 tenancy is a set of site collections in either a SharePoint farm or in SharePoint Online. In SharePoint Online, the site collections belong to a single customer account. In a SharePoint farm, the site collections can be all the site collections in a SharePoint web application or a subset of them, or it can be a set of site collections from across multiple web applications in the farm.

**It seems that it's still unclear what tenant is, so here is more info**

In order to understand what a tenant is, the concept of [multitenancy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy) should be explained.

> **Multitenancy** referes to a principal in software architecture where a single instance of the software runs on a server, serving multiple tenants.  A tenant is a group of users sharing the same view on the software they use.

From [this](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/sharepoint-online-farm-multitenancy.html) link, you can see an illustration of a tenant:
[image]

Given this information, you can liken a tenant to a Web Application.

Given this, your second and third questions do not make sense.

For your fourth question, yes, Microsoft creates everything on the back end.

<strike>You'll need to clarify your fifth question.</strike>
From your comment below: what is the scope of the tenant?

There is no scope to a tenant.  A tenant is set of site collections, that is all.

Comment: 5th question: in office 365 what is the scope of tenant which MS creates for you?

Comment: Is tenant required for web scoped apps?

Comment: wjevris, as you couldn't answer web scoped apps I need reply from other senior experts.

Comment: I have some idea, till want to clarify from senior experts. Thanks

Comment: @Sunil, you seem to somehow down talk a very good answer. If I may guess, this is due to a lack of a basic understanding of the Office 365 and SharePoint Online? Maybe you should start your research by doing some web searches to try to grasp the basics of where and how SharePoint Online differs from SharePoint 2013?

Comment: If some interviewer asked you what is the scope of tenant, then what will be your answer? I don't think thew statement of @wjervis "There is no scope to a tenant. A tenant is set of site collections, that is all." is correct at all? Please clarify my doubt asap.

Comment: Then the person asking the question probably doesn't understand what a tenant is, or needs to better clarify what they are asking.